# columns property for pasting the row

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I have the code for copying the particular row and paste it in particular column
the code is

```
 Range(rng, rng.End(xlToRight)).copy
 Columns(c).Offset(, 6).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```

It is working correctly
But when i wanted to start pasting it from 2 cell of particular column i,e

```
 Range(rng, rng.End(xlToRight)).copy
 Columns(c).Offset(2, 6).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```

it is giving 
"object defined error"

please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Cells(2, Cells(1,Columns(c).Column).offset(,6).Column).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```

In the above ling you are selecting Row 2 by `Cells(2,` and 6 columns to the right of whatever c is by `Columns(c).Column).Offset(,6).Column)`

The reason that `Columns(c).Offset(2,6)` does not work is because you are telling excel to Offset an `Entire Column` by 2 rows, which you can't since it would effectively push the data off the worksheet.

You can offset `EntireColumns` for a given number of columns and `EntireRows` for a given number of rows, but not `EntireColumns` by Rows and `EntireRows` by Columns.

Comment: I really think, that  `Cells(1,Columns(c).Column).offset(,6).Column` is not too straightforward a way of saying `c+6`

Comment: I agree, except I happen to know that `c` is passed as a letter, and not a number, so that won't work. I know `c` is passed as a column letter (string) because I have been seeing @M_S_SAJJAN code on SO for a few days now.

Answer (score 2):

You can't offset a column by row, column is always whole. You should offset a cell.

```
Columns(c).cells(1).Offset(1, 6).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```

or

```
Columns(c).cells(2).Offset(, 6).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```

or

```
Columns(c).cells(2, 7).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```

or

```
cells(2, c+6).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```